# golang action on specific days of the week (ie. every Friday)

Tags: mysql, time, go

I need to get a specific day of the week inbetween a period such as for every sunday between 2015-08-17 to 2015-10-14 so I've end up with this.

```
    onDate, err := time.Parse(dateFormat, startDate)
    if err != nil {
        logr.Println(err)
    }

    offDate, err := time.Parse(dateFormat, stopDate)
    if err != nil {
        logr.Println(err)
    }

    weekday := onDate.Weekday()

    getDay := int(weekday)

    a := onDate.YearDay()
    b := offDate.YearDay()

    var date string
    var z time.Time

// Sundaytime1 is entered in the browser and will always be the same
    if sundayTime1 != "" && getDay == 0 {
        for a <= b {
            z := onDate.AddDate(0, 0, 7)
            date := time.Parse(dateFormat, z)

            fmt.Println(onDate)
            _, err = que.Exec(studyID, msgid, date, sundayTime1, 0, 0)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            fmt.Println("I'm a Sunday!")
            a = a + 7

        }
    }
```

This does increment the day by on but it only does it once so it returns `2015-08-23 00:00:00 +0000 UTC` repeatedly. and i can't seem to get it to only return `2015-08-23` but it does only perform a database entry for every Sunday between the time. but its the wrong date and it shouldn't include the time. The downside being i have one of these for every possible starting day of the week. Is there a better way to handle this and how i only get `2015-08-23` without the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might work for you: http://play.golang.org/p/UGnV8kPrA3

as you are dealing with instances in time, the end date is semantically the date before the time instance `2015-10-14T00:00:00` + 1 day